# Import eclipse project as Java EE

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, jakarta-ee

I have created a Java EE project using maven and would like to import it as a Java EE project (ie: auto have the libs jars added to the classpath, tomcat jars to classpath, etc).  How can I change an existing project to a Java EE project?

Comment: @wuntee Its a maven project, it doesn't matter whether its J2EE project or not, just add dependencies which you need to you pom and you're ready to do whatever "J2EE Project" is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the [maven-eclipse-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) and the Eclipse [M2Eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) plugin can handle this use case and make Eclipse treat your war/ejb/ear projects as WTP projects.

For the maven-eclipse-plugin, check the [WTP support](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/wtp.html) page (you can of course add this parameter to the `<configuration>` element of the plugin).

For the M2Eclipse plugin, make sure you also install the **Maven Integration for WTP** (which is optional) or you won't get WTP support. Note that for a `war` module, the plugin will set the **Dynamic Web Module** facet version on the basis of the version of **`web.xml`** (2.3, 2.4, 2.5) and the version can't be changed once the project has been imported. So make sure to have the "right" `web.xml` before the import (or delete the project from the workspace, change the `web.xml` and re-import the project).

Comment: I am using m2eclipse - even when creating a project through the Eclipse m2eclipse gui, it still does not show the project as a web project... Meaning, there is no icon of a globe, and there is no option to run the project as "run on server"...  I do have Maven Integration for WTP...

Comment: @wuntee Is the WTP working for other (non maven) projects? What is the packaging of the created project?

Comment: after updating all of eclipse it started working fine.  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [m2eclipse plugin](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/). It will tell Eclipse which JARs to include and you can manage all your dependencies in the `pom.xml`.